# I'm writing a simple verilog code, having little trouble

Tags: verilog, code

In the image shown below, there says a syntax error at line 10. Its a basic If statement, i dont know why the syntax error shows up. Please advise
[image: Line 9 says syntax error. Will attach image of error also]

[image: error message]

Comment: Did you cut and paste the code from a web page? If so, it’s possible your whitespaces are not ASCII tabs/spaces. Try deleting the spaces before the “if” and typing them again.

Comment: Oh yes i wrote it on notepad and copied onto my geedit via a pen drive. It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The octal \037777777640 values shown in the error appear to be interpretations of no-break spaces (which might come from copy-and-pasting from the web, for example). NBSP has a Hex value of 0xA0, which would equate to the octal values you’re seeing.

Try deleting all of your spaces and retyping them.

Comment: That must be a common error...